# Manipulating lists using append node in groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to parse a xml file into a list. Then use nested loop into the list and append new nodes.

This is the code i have written

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import groovy.xml.*;

    def scresp        = '''
    <root>
    <Customer>
    <CustomerID>100</CustomerID>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
    <CustomerID>101</CustomerID>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
    <CustomerID>102</CustomerID>
    </Customer>
    </root>'''

          def reslist       = new XmlSlurper().parseText(scresp)
          def str = ''
          reslist.each
          {line ->
              line.Customer.eachWithIndex { cust, idx ->
                  str = "Count: " + idx
                  println str
                  cust.appendNode{
                      Count(idx)
                      Sample(str)}
                } }

        def updatedPayload = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield reslist }.toString()
        println updatedPayload
```

The output i'm getting is

```
Count: 0
Count: 1
Count: 2
<root>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerID>100</CustomerID>
        <Sample>Count: 2</Sample>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerID>101</CustomerID>
        <Sample>Count: 2</Sample>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerID>102</CustomerID>
        <Sample>Count: 2</Sample>
    </Customer>
</root>
```

My question is why only the last value 'Count: 2' is added to the xml though the println str returns correct values Count: 0, Count: 1 & Count: 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Streaming builder which is lazy. That means, that it during execution it gets the actual (most recent) value of the global variable `str`.

In order to make it right, you have to reduce the scope of the variable:

```
          // def str = '' // << delete this line
          reslist.each
          {line ->
              line.Customer.eachWithIndex { cust, idx ->
                  String str = "Count: " + idx // declare the variable here
                  println str
                  cust.appendNode{
                      Count(idx)
                      Sample(str)}
                } }
```

Then it prints out:

```
<root>
<Customer><CustomerID>100</CustomerID><Count>0</Count><Sample>Count: 0</Sample></Customer>
<Customer><CustomerID>101</CustomerID><Count>1</Count><Sample>Count: 1</Sample></Customer>
<Customer><CustomerID>102</CustomerID><Count>2</Count><Sample>Count: 2</Sample></Customer>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!